# Electric field in conductor at equilibrium: explanations seem to be lacking

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors, coulombs-law

I'm trying to understand why the field is zero.  This is not a duplicate of previous similar questions because I'm questioning the standard explanations.

I've seen two explanations:

1. Gauss's law.
2. A nonzero field would contradict equilibrium.

First, the Gauss Law explanation.  The reasoning goes that the charge migrates to the conductor's surface, and thus a Gauss surface in the interior encloses zero charge, so the flux through the Gauss surface must be $0$, and therefore he field must be $0$ too.  This doesn't seem right for two reasons.
First, why must the charge be located only on the surface?  (In fact, it's usually explained the other way around: once we establish that the field is $0$ in the conductor's interior, Guass's law immediately implies that no charge can be present there.)  One might argue that the charges repel each other and therefore end up on the surface, although what's to prevent some point charge from being equally repelled from all directions and thus remaining in the interior (e.g., a point charge at the center of a ball).  But let's assume we can prove independently that all the charge must be on the conductor's surface.  The problem remains that although Gauss's law then implies that the total flux through a Gauss surface in the interior is $0$, this in no way implies that the field is $0$, only that the total flux entering the surface equals that exiting it.  (To drive the point home, consider a point charge and a gauss surface, say a sphere, next to it (but not containing it).  There is no charge within the sphere.  Does that mean the field there is $0$ ?)  Typical applications of Gauss's law usually invoke symmetry to infer that the electric field is uniform over the Gauss surface, so it can be factored out of the integral, and in that case $\textrm{flux}=0$  indeed implies $\textrm{field}=0$.  However, for a non symmetric conductor this argument breaks.

Turning to the equilibrium argument, the only thing that can be inferred from equilibrium is that if there is charge in the conductor's interior, then the field there must be $0$, but in fact we know there is no charge there, so how can a nonzero field there contradict equilibrium?  The equilibrium argument works at the conductor's surface to show that the field there must be perpendicular to the surface, but I don't see how it applies to the conductor's interior, which is charge free.

So I guess my question is: can the statement that the electric field is zero inside a charged conductor be proven solely from Coulomb's law?

Comment: Just by the by, Coulomb's Law comes from Gauss' Law.

Comment: It sure can be derived from it, and (not being a physicist) I won't argue which of them is more fundamental, but that's not the way textbooks teach it.

Comment: an conductor with absolute  zero resistivity that is a closed vaccum space(considering no external interaction) that can freely conduct any charge it is given doesn't exist. superconductors have very negligible internal resistance,implying they have nucleus and free electrons in them,so in electron proton model.due to free charge,the case where a + charge is surrounded by spherical + charges causing net field at inside charge to be zero cannot happen,as + charge inside will spherically attract free electrons till all +charge distributes to surface

Comment: 1. The question is about an idealized model, not whether it can actually occur in reality.
2. As I wrote, "But let's assume we can prove independently that all the charge must be on the conductor's surface...".  The question of whether a charge may be perfectly balanced inside the conductor is a side issue here.

Comment: so,are you asking that in a hollow conductor,why does the electric field inside conductor is zero?if that is the ask,we can again use equillibrium argument,because even if the conductor is hollow,its coverage will have a very very small thickness,which will cause the electrons to move in such a way till the electric field in that thick layer is not zero,so now,if electric field in that layer is zero,no flux is entering the inner surface,meaning,no electric field inside the hollow space

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the surface is thick or thin.  I'm taking as read that the charges are on the surface.  The fact that they are not moving means that the field component parallel to the surface is 0, but what is to say that there is no perpendicular component outward?  That is precisely my question.  The model is that charges are not free to move off the conductor due to unspecified forces counteracting any force pushing them away, so not moving perpendicularly doesn't imply 0 electric field (due to the charges) in that direction.

Comment: In fact, there clearly is net flux through parts of the surface; only the total flux over all the surface is 0.  How do you prove there is 0 field inside?

Comment: The General Argument of equilibrium goes the other way,First We prove by contradiction that in a Metal conductor,Electric Field Must be zero ,Otherwise Electrons Will move till equilibrium is reached,Later,We use gauss law to prove if electric field is zero,charge can only reside on surface,Later for conductors having cavities,We Use the argument That suppose the Cavity was made by cutting part of Complete solid conductor,Then as charges then resided on surface,E=0 for that space,now,cavity solid Is removed,Which will have no effect On Charge configuration,Which still makes E=0 inside cavity

Comment: ",First We prove by contradiction that in a Metal conductor,Electric Field Must be zero ,Otherwise Electrons Will move till equilibrium is reached."  Why does electrons-not-moving imply that field must be zero everywhere?  It only implies that it's 0 in a given region if there are electrons that can move in that region.  If the interior is free of charge, then charges are not moving in the interior simply because they are not present there, not necessarily because the field there is 0.

Comment: what does this statement imply"its zero in region if there are electrons that can move in that region,if interior is free of charge,charges are not moving simply beacuse they are not present there",there are always electrons in conductor which are in conduction band,and still net charge inside conductos is zero,because every electrons has its corresponding proton in that conductor,its just that the conduction band electrons are weakly bounded to metal atoms which causes them to move freely if there is any external field applied(in this case as unbalanced charge is given,it has its field)

Comment: by "No charge inside interior",are you implying that there is a cavity?,if that's the case,I already gave argument to support that,But if you are trying to say that if metal conductor is neutral,it has no charge,inhibiting electron movement,in that case you are thinking incorrect,as that would be the case for insulators,beacause in conductors,electrons can roam around freely like a sea of electrons,which is not the case for insulators

Comment: [Rewriting this response.] None of this is relevant to the model as I understand it, where "conductor" simply means that charge is free to move within but not escape.  Let me rephrase the question.  Imagine a region of empty space in which some negative point charges are placed. There is nothing else in the universe.  Also, there is a new law of nature that prevents the charges from escaping the region but has no effect otherwise.  The charges repel each other, move to the region's edges, and reach equilibrium.  Is the field within the region 0 everywhere?  If so, how can it be deduced?

Answer (score 1):

> the only thing that can be inferred from equilibrium is that if there is charge in the conductor's interior, then the field there must be 0, but in fact we know there is no charge there, so how can a nonzero field there contradict equilibrium?

You may be confusing the assumption of zero *net* charge and zero charge.

The interior of the conductor consists of many fixed charges (atomic nuclei and most of the electrons) and many mobile charges (the valence electrons).  Normally these are paired so that the total net charge is zero.  When discussing the charge on a conductor ($Q$), we mean the total net charge.

But an electric field doesn't affect only the net charge, it creates forces on all charges.  Inside a conductor, this means that an electric field would accelerate the mobile charges.  The interior is not charge free.

Comment: Well, the model of an idealized conductor is (to my understanding) a body in which point charges may move freely, and these are the only charges to be reckoned with.  If you add to the model fixed protons and mobile electrons, then equilibrium could be achieved even with a nonzero field in some point or region in the interior, provided that the electrons have all been evacuated from there.  The protons would constitute a non-zero net charge, and that wouldn't contradict equilibrium because they are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> why must the charge be located only on the surface?

Only net charge density must be zero inside, not density of the mobile charge carriers(in metals, electrons). There are still charge carriers inside the metal, in fact the inside is electrically in the same state regardless of whether there is some surface charge or not.

The reason net charge density must be zero inside is the Gauss law combined with non-zero conductivity of the metal. Gauss's law requires that if charge density at some point is non-zero, electric field has to vary in space at that point. But then the electric field at some point nearby would have to be non-zero. Non-zero electric field would make the mobile charge carriers move (due to non-zero conductivity), electric current would occur. Such current would move the system to a state closer to the equilibrium state, where net charge density and electric field is zero inside.

Mathematically, this can be described as follows. We can formulate differential equation for charge density in ohmic conductor.

Ohm's law:
$$
\mathbf j = \sigma \mathbf E
$$

Law of local conservation of charge:

$$
\partial_t \rho = -\nabla\cdot \mathbf j
$$

Combining these two, we obtain

$$
\partial_t \rho = - \sigma \nabla \cdot \mathbf E
$$

Now we can use the Gauss law $\nabla \cdot \mathbf E = \rho/\epsilon_0$ and obtain

$$
\partial_t \rho = -\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}\rho
$$

Solution of this equations is a decaying exponential function of time. Thus if some charge gets implanted inside the metal, its density decays very fast to zero.

Comment: Your answer is convincing if we assume charge density is finite everywhere, but if we allow point charges, then what's to prevent a point charge from remaining in the center of a ball, as I've asked?  But, again, my main problem is not with the assumption that the net charge in the interior is 0.  As I wrote, even accepting that, how does it follow that the field must be 0?

Comment: Point charge of macroscopic charge magnitude would have macroscopic Coulomb electric field around it and this field would act on the mobile charge carriers around it and electric current would occur, which would mean the body is not in equilibrium. This process is described by the equations above. Your main problem is resolved by the same argument as in the first half of my answer: non-zero field would mean electric current, which would contradict equilibrium.

Comment: Doesn't non-zero field imply current only if there are charged particles present within the region of that non-zero field?  How can a non-zero field in the interior of the conductor induce current if all the mobile charge carriers have already rearranged themselves on its surface?

Comment: There are always mobile charged particles present in the interior of the conductor. Pulling all of them to the surface would require insane amount of energy and extreme external electric field; the charges would be pulled back by the positive nuclei with extreme forces. What (in statics) usually ends up on the surface is only excess charged particles, and if there are none (neutral body), what happens is only a small part of all available charge rearranges a little. The interiour hardly ever changes in statics; it takes time-varying fields to disturb the concentration there.

Comment: Right.  Let's accept that there are electrons in the interior held in place by the fixed protons.  Because they are fixed, even if there were a non-zero field in the interior, the electrons would still stay in place, so the fact that they aren't moving doesn't imply nonzero field.  For this reason, the standard model of charged conductor (as I understand it) ignores the issue entirely, and just assumes there is some charge (in reality, the excess) that is free to move within the conductor.  Once that charge relocates to the surface, there is no charge in the interior.

Comment: @Ari, no, in conductors there are electrons inside that are not held in place by the fixed protons. What you are describing is isolator.

Answer (score 0):

In short, i can present a proof directly from the l
Laplace equation,but using coulombs law, it is impossible to prove that at an interior point in a conductor,the field is zero, without any prior knowledge of the geometry and surface charge distribution $\sigma$.

**PROOF**

Consider the arbitrary surface which bounds the conductor to be $S$. Let $V$ be the electrostatic potential function. Note that in the region bounded by $S$,  $\nabla ^2 V = 0$at all points inside $S$,because the interior is charge free(this is basically because $\nabla . \vec E = - \nabla ^2 V = q/{\epsilon_0}$.). We also know that the potential at the boundary surface $S$ is constant over it. So $V(S) = C$ for some constant potential C. Now, the Uniqueness theorem in electrostatics tells us that, if there exists some 2 solutions for the potential function, $V_1$ and $V_2$ satisfying the laplace equation, and having $V_1(S)= V_2(S) = C$, then $V_1 = V_2$ for all points, i.e there exists a unique solution given the boundary conditions. Clearly, if we can guess one solution for $V$ satisfying the laplace equation and having $V(S) = C$, then it is guranteed that this $V$ must be the only possible solution. One can trivially see that $V = C$ everywhere inside $S$ satisfies both the laplace equation and the boundary conditions. In other words, the potential at any interior point is the same as the surface potential C. By definition of potential, then $\nabla V = -\vec E = 0$ at all interior points.

NOTE: you can also extend this proof for the case of a conductor with cavities. I sugeest you read up on the uniqueness theorem.

Comment: There are two assumptions here.  The first is that the boundary surface is equipotential.   Presumably, if it hadn't been, then some charge on the surface would be accelerating.  I'm not sure there isn't some weird geometry and charge density distribution in which there would be a charge free area on the surface with a non-constant potential there, but I'm willing to accept that either this is in fact impossible, or is so esoteric as to never occur in practice.  The second assumption is that the interior is charge free.  Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go back to the definition of an idealized conductor. The defining property of a conductor is that there is an unlimited amount of free charge available. I.e. at any point inside the material there are positive and negative charges that are free to move. If there's an electric field present in the interior then the charges that are present at that point will feel forces and move around.

If we have equilibrium then there can't be an internal field. If there were then free charges would move and the system wasn't actually in equilibrium. Jan's answer contains a quantitative  description of this fact.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, the key is that there is *unlimited* amount of free charge available. However, if that is the case, then we are not justified in assuming that equilibrium is necessarily reached.  Charge (positive and negative cancelling each other) can just keep flowing forever from the interior to the surface.  There's an unlimited amount of it, after all.

Comment: You're right -- and you don't always have this equilibrium in a conductor. For instance, if you wrap a wire around the conductor and drive an oscillating current through it the changing B fields will certainly induce E fields in the conductor. But *if* you are in equilibrium then there is no E field in a conductor.

Comment: The context of the question is not one in which an external fluctuating field is applied.  Let's assume the universe is empty except for the charged conductor.

Comment: Then I think it's reasonable that the situation will eventually come to an equilibrium. And once reached, the electric field must be zero inside.

Comment: But that's exactly my question.  Why does equilibrium on the surface necessarily imply zero field in the interior?

Comment: I'm not sure what equilibrium on the surface means. What I'm saying is that if the conductor gets to a point where all the charges everywhere have stopped moving then the field must be zero inside the conductor. Intuitively we know that the whole thing must come to equilibrium, i.e. a static set of external fields is not going to do an infinite amount of work creating perpetual currents. But I'll think about how to show that more mathematically, e.g. using Maxwell's eqs.

Comment: That makes sense if you assume a realistic model of reality, in which there is a finite amount of charge (either carried by a finite number of discrete point charges, or as a density distribution).  If you do so, then the charge eventually stops moving and is located entirely on the surface.  Once that happens, why is it necessarily true that the field in the interior is 0?  If your answer is the unrealistic assumption that there is infinite charge in the interior that would otherwise keep moving, then it is not more unrealistic to ask why should those charges ever stop moving.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a conductor is a material where electrons can easily move from atom to atom. With this in mind, a conductor must be equipotential because otherwise, the electrons will freely move until the charge density is constant everywhere (basically because all electrons will feel the same force). Since the electric field is the rate of change of the electric potential along a direction, we can conclude that the electric field must be zero inside a conductor.

Comment: You say *otherwise, the electrons will freely move until the charge density is constant everywhere* but in fact that would not make it equipotential.  The claim is actually that they would all move to the surface, and then the interior would be equipotential.  But if there are no electrons in the interior, why must it be equipotential.